# Edit HTML in Android?

Tags: android, html, webview

I have a locally stored HTML file in my `assets` folder that I am accessing through this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Global.setUpButton(this);
    WebView webView = new WebView(this);
    setContentView(webView);

    //Sets up the settings for the webView
    webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/map.html");
    webView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
    webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webView.setInitialScale(0);
}
```

I was wondering if there is any way I would be able to view and/or edit the source of the HTML file loaded, as I may need to manipulate certain elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a workaround instead.

Created a JavascriptInterface that will allow me to append any HTML tags I need to. This is easier because I won't have to reload the page, which reduces loading time.

Answer (score 0):

Sure. You create a layout with an EditText box, you load the file and display it in the box, then after editing, you store the new string in the file.

added:

You can use AssetManager to read the data as a String from the URL. Then you put the string in the EditText. Then the user edits it. Then you get the edited html from the editText, and do what you wanted to do with it in the first place. If I understand your questions correctly.

Comment: I understand what method you are trying to use, but how can I possibly load the HTML source into the `EditText`?

Comment: You have a locally stored html file, then you edit it with javascript. Right.